# Problems setting stored background color for ListView index

Tags: java, android

I made a note-taking app using a ListView layout. The user can click on a note and set its color. That color is applied to the EditText background and to its corresponding ListView item. However, the colors reset when I exit the app. How can I set the saved color configurations for each ListView index whenever the app is opened?

I tried using SharedPreferences to save and load the colors but I keep getting errors and the app wont even open. I also tried tagging the colors suggested by another StackOverflow post but I get the same errors.

MainActivity.java

```
 static int pos = 0;
 static String c = "";
 static ListView listBackground;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 listBackground = findViewById(R.id.listView);

 // LOAD DATA FROM EditNote.java
 sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.example.syeds.notesapp", MODE_PRIVATE);

 //ATTEMPT TO SET COLOR OF CHILD  
 for(int count = 0; count < notes.size(); count++){
            String color = sharedPreferences.getString("color", null);
            listBackground.getChildAt(count).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));

        }


 final ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    //THIS IS WHERE USER IS TAKEN TO EditNote.java   ` 
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EditNote.class);       
            intent.putExtra("notePosition",position);     
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

EditNote.java

```
String color;
int position;

 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    //Get the position of array index
    position = intent.getIntExtra("notePosition", -1);

} 
    //EXAMPLE METHOD FOR ONE COLOR(OTHERS NOT INCLUDED IN SAMPLE)
    public void changeGreen(View view) {   

    //Set color
    color = "#D4EFDF";
    MainActivity.listBackground.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));

    //ATTEMPT TO SAVE COLOR
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString("color",color).apply();


    //Sets background of EditText
    background = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    background.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D4EFDF"));
}
```

For all the things I tried that are mentioned above, I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char java.lang.String.charAt(int)' on a null object reference
    at android.graphics.Color.parseColor(Color.java:1384)
    at com.example.syeds.notesapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
```

Comment: Also you are using for loop to get colors from the sharedPreferences. Do you realize that you can save only only color at a time? So everytime when you loop, you are getting the same color from the preferences

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to loop through the ListView elements and apply the colors previously set by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way, hopefully it will work because I am doing something similar in my app and it works fine:

TO SAVE COLORS:

```
SharedPreferences mPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("color", color);
editor.commit();
```

TO RETRIEVE COLOR:

```
color = mPreferences.getString("color", "#FFF");
```

Comment: I can save colors but how do I prevent the colors from disappearing each time the app is rebooted? I always get an null object reference for the ListView index

Comment: from your error, it seems like you are not saving colors into shared preferences

Comment: It gives an error because I'm attempting to invoke a method onto a null object reference, which is the listView index. This happens because my method tries to assign colors to specific indexes in onCreate. If an index is deleted, that results in a null pointer since the color cant be assigned to a non-existing index.